# Merge 3 arrays based on specific index and create new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have three arrays in which first index is same, so i want to merge all three array into one array based on first index element

Input:

```
[[1, 'A'], [2, 'B'], [3, 'C']];
[[1, 'D'], [2, 'E'], [3, 'F']];
[[1, 'G'], [2, 'H'], [3, 'I']];
```

Expected output

```
[ 
  [ 1, 'A', 'D', 'G' ], 
  [ 2, 'B', 'E', 'H' ], 
  [ 3, 'C', 'F', 'I' ] 
]
```

My code:

```
function mergeArrays(arrays) {
  const mergedMap = new Map();

  for (const array of arrays) {
    for (const item of array) {
      const key = item[0];
      if (!mergedMap.has(key)) {
        mergedMap.set(key, [key]);
      }
      mergedMap.get(key).push(...item.slice(1));
    }
  }

  const mergedArray = Array.from(mergedMap.values());

  return mergedArray;
}

const array1 = [[1, 'A'], [2, 'B'], [3, 'C']];
const array2 = [[1, 'D'], [2, 'E'], [3, 'F']];
const array3 = [[1, 'G'], [2, 'H'], [3, 'I']];

const mergedResult = mergeArrays([array1, array2, array3]);
console.log(mergedResult);
```

Would you please suggest any better solution?

Please note: for the simplicity i have make first index as number but in my case it is a Date object.

Comment: If you have a piece of code that already works, it might be more suitable for [codereview.se].

Comment: Looks like just a group-by [How to group two-dimensional array by value at zero index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71289548/how-to-group-two-dimensional-array-by-value-at-zero-index)

Answer (score 0):

lodash version as below

```js
const _ = require('lodash');
function mergeArrays(arrays) {
  return _.chain(arrays)
    .flatten()
    .groupBy((item) => item[0])
    .mapValues(L1=>_.uniq(_.flatten(L1)))
    .values()
    .value();
}

const array1 = [[1, 'A'], [2, 'B'], [3, 'C']];
const array2 = [[1, 'D'], [2, 'E'], [3, 'F']];
const array3 = [[1, 'G'], [2, 'H'], [3, 'I']];

const mergedResult = mergeArrays([array1, array2, array3]);
console.log(mergedResult);

//output as you want
[ 
  [ 1, 'A', 'D', 'G' ], 
  [ 2, 'B', 'E', 'H' ], 
  [ 3, 'C', 'F', 'I' ] 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

That kind of function is usually known as `zip` but as you have three arrays let's call it `zip3`:

```
function zip3(f, a, b, c) {
  var ret = [];
  var max = Math.min(a.length, b.length, c.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) ret.push(f(a[i], b[i], c[i]));
  return ret;
}
```

It applies `f` to elements at the same index e.g. `f(a[0], b[0], c[0])`. Since each element is also an array we need [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to access the data.

Examples:

```
zip3( ([index, a], [, b], [, c]) => [index, a, b, c]
    , [[1,'A'],[2,'B'],[3,'C']]
    , [[1,'D'],[2,'E'],[3,'F']]
    , [[1,'G'],[2,'H'],[3,'I']]);

//=> [[1,'A','D','G']
//=> ,[2,'B','E','H']
//=> ,[3,'C','F','I']]

zip3( ([index, a], [, b], [, c]) => [c, b, a, index-1]
    , [[1,'A'],[2,'B'],[3,'C']]
    , [[1,'D'],[2,'E'],[3,'F']]
    , [[1,'G'],[2,'H'],[3,'I']]);

//=> [['G','D','A',0]
//=> ,['H','E','B',1]
//=> ,['I','F','C',2]]

zip3( ([index, a], [,b], [,c]) => ({x: a, y: b, z: c, index})
    , [[1,'A'],[2,'B'],[3,'C']]
    , [[1,'D'],[2,'E'],[3,'F']]
    , [[1,'G'],[2,'H'],[3,'I']]);

//=> [{x: 'A', y: 'D', z: 'G', index: 1}
//=> ,{x: 'B', y: 'E', z: 'H', index: 2}
//=> ,{x: 'C', y: 'F', z: 'I', index: 3}]
```