# how to group double nested arrays based on index in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a newbie in JavaScript so any suggestion would be much appreciated.

I have this array:

```
var mixedArray = [["online","abc","def"],["offline","ghi","jkl"],["online","mno","pqr"],["offline","stu","vwx"] ]
```

I want to output like this:

```
var array1 = [["online","abc","def"],["online","mno","pqr"]]
var array2 = [["offline","ghi","jkl"],["offline","stu","vwx"]]
```

Is there any method to make that solution?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the grouping logic based on? Every odd index and every even index is grouped together? Or is it based on the fact that both nested arrays have `"online"` as index 0, and the other has `"offline"`?

Comment: hello, Nick. grouping logic is based on Online and Offline. so var Array 1 has all the "online" and the var array2 has all the "offline"

Comment: Do you only have two values, "online" and "offline", and not possible another?

Comment: and yes, grouping based on sub-array's index 0 which is "online" and "offline".
and in the future, this sub-array's index 0 will be more than 2 events, there will be "error", "hold" etc. and index 1,2 are just basicly their timestamps

Comment: or [How to group two-dimensional array by value at zero index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71289548/how-to-group-two-dimensional-array-by-value-at-zero-index)

Answer (score 2):

If you can support the new [`Object.groupBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy) method (which there are [polyfills for](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#array-grouping) if you can't), then you can use that to create an object where each `"offline"` array is grouped to the key `offline` and each `"online"` array is grouped to the key `online`, once done, you can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `offline` and `online` values from this grouped object to use them as separate arrays:

```js
const mixedArray = [["online","abc","def"],["offline","ghi","jkl"],["online","mno","pqr"],["offline","stu","vwx"] ]
const { online, offline } = Object.groupBy(mixedArray, ([onOrOff]) => onOrOff);

console.log(online); // array1
console.log(offline); // array2
```

Here is an example alternative if you can't support `.groupBy`, where you can create your own implementation:

```js
const mixedArray = [["online","abc","def"],["offline","ghi","jkl"],["online","mno","pqr"],["offline","stu","vwx"] ]
const { online, offline } = groupBy(mixedArray, ([onOrOff]) => onOrOff);

console.log(online); // array1
console.log(offline); // array2

// Rough implementation of Object.groupBy (https://tc39.es/proposal-array-grouping/#sec-object.groupby)
function groupBy(arr, fn) {
  const obj = Object.create(null);
  let k = 0;
  for(const val of arr) {
    const key = fn(val, k++);
    
    if (key in obj) obj[key].push(val);
    else obj[key] = [val];
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: hello thank you for the speedy answer, its working!,

Comment: now i have to implement the code into my real code consisting a lot of data, of its not a problem as well

Comment: @Fkofree19 No worries, I've added a second code snippet to show a more backward-compatible version if needed.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could group these arrays, assuming each group is either `online` or `offline` uses [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var mixedArray = [["online","abc","def"],["offline","ghi","jkl"],["online","mno","pqr"],["offline","stu","vwx"] ]
array1 = mixedArray.filter((item) => item[0] == "online");
array2 = mixedArray.filter((item) => item[0] == "offline");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create a grouping of elements based on the first item in each row

```js
var mixedArray = [
  ["online", "abc", "def"],
  ["offline", "ghi", "jkl"],
  ["online", "mno", "pqr"],
  ["offline", "stu", "vwx"]
];

const groupedBy = mixedArray.reduce((groups, array) => {
  const key = array[0];
  if (groups[key]) {
    groups[key].push(array)
  } else {
    groups[key] = [array]
  }
  return groups;
}, {});

console.log(groupedBy);
```

Answer (score 0):

An one-liner would do it easily.

The task seems as splitting an array into two based on a boolean flag (represented as 'online'/'offline'). You can use `Array::reduce()`:

```js
const arr = [["online","abc","def"],["offline","ghi","jkl"],["online","mno","pqr"],["offline","stu","vwx"]];

const [array1, array2] = arr.reduce((r, item) => (r[+(item[0] === 'offline')].push(item), r), [[],[]]);

console.log(...array1.map(JSON.stringify));
console.log(...array2.map(JSON.stringify));
```

```
` Chrome/119
-----------------------------------------------------------
Alexander      1.00x  |  x10000000  232  237  240  242  245
Gabriele       3.04x  |  x10000000  705  708  711  724  728
Nick Parsons   3.13x  |  x10000000  727  739  747  747  758
-----------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const arr = [["online","abc","def"],["offline","ghi","jkl"],["online","mno","pqr"],["offline","stu","vwx"]];

// @benchmark Nick Parsons

// Rough implementation of Object.groupBy (https://tc39.es/proposal-array-grouping/#sec-object.groupby)
function groupBy(arr, fn) {
  const obj = Object.create(null);
  let k = 0;
  for(const val of arr) {
const key = fn(val, k++);

if (key in obj) obj[key].push(val);
else obj[key] = [val];
  }
  return obj;
}

groupBy(arr, ([onOrOff]) => onOrOff);

// @benchmark Gabriele

arr.reduce((groups, array) => {
  const key = array[0];
  if (groups[key]) {
    groups[key].push(array)
  } else {
    groups[key] = [array]
  }
  return groups;
}, {});

// @benchmark Alexander

arr.reduce((r, item) => (r[+(item[0] === 'offline')].push(item), r), [[],[]]);

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```